# Wrong output to web browser

Tags: javascript

I tryed show into browser date and time, but have wrong output.
Maybe I miss something but I can't catch what it is?
Encoding is `ANSI`.

**Output:**
`Current date and time` - it's all output.

**Code:**

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Show date‹</TITLE></HEAD>
        <BODY>
            <H1>Current date and time</H1>
            <p>
                <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                    now = new Date();
                    localtime = now.toString();
                    utctime = now.toGMTString();
                    hours = now.getHours();
                    mins = now.getMinutes();
                    secs = now.getSeconds();
                     document.write("<b>Current time: </b>" + localtime + "<BR>");
                     document.write("<b>Asolute time: </b>" + utctime + "</p>");
                     document.write("<font size='+5'>");
                        document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
                     document.write("</font>);
                </SCRIPT>
        </BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Question:**

- How do solve this problem?

Comment: Your last document.write is missing a `"` at the end

Comment: syntax error, forgot to close double quotes at closing font. Btw this is why tool like chrome developer tool or firebug helps a lot.

Comment: @Bojan Kovacevic can you display how this tools help warn error? I'm beginner at java script.

Comment: well for example you can activate chrome developer tool (if you use chrome) with f12. then after page load,if there is some syntax error in your javascript you will have error printed in console tab of developer tool (lower part of the screen). Also you could click there to see on which line is error.

Comment: @Bojan Kovacevic What you can say about Java Script enviroment for developers. Which are more useful?

Comment: @nazar_art that really depents on your preferences. If you meant can i compare chrome devel tool and firebug, i personally think they are both very good. I used to use firebug before, but lately i prefere chrome browser (so also chrome devel tools) as in my experience firefox tend to be slower. But both are good ...

Comment: @Bojan Kovacevic Can you recomend some chrome devel tools tutorial?

Comment: @nazar_art start [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) but i myself learn best after i get to debugging my pages and when i explore the tool options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this code part:

```
  document.write("<font size='+5'>");
     document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
  document.write("</font>);
</SCRIPT>
```

You missed `"` mark here => `document.write("</font>");`